# OpenCV mean differentiate

Tags: c++, arrays, opencv, mean

I have a column-based(each column is a feature) large array(around 100M) which has dimensions of 75000(fixed)*number of samples

This is data vector:

```
std::vector<float> features;
```

I have used this code to calculate mean:

```
cv::Mat data(FEATURE_SIZE, features.size()/FEATURE_SIZE, CV_32F, &features[0]);
cv::reduce(data,dataMeans,1,CV_REDUCE_AVG);
```

`FEATURE_SIZE` is 75000 and `features` is a float vector which has all the data.

In order to calculate mean shift I used this:

```
data -= cv::repeat(dataMeans,1,features.size()/FEATURE_SIZE);
```

Which I think tries to create an array of same size with my `features` array and therefore giving me a bad allocation exception.

I just need that array to be mean differentiated. Is there any way to do it without copying, on the same memory location?

Answer (score 0):

First, you messed up columns and rows.
Here a correct way to do what you want:

```
#define FEATURES_SIZE 3

int main()
{
    vector<float> features = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};

    Mat1f data(features.size() / FEATURES_SIZE, FEATURES_SIZE, &features[0]);
    Mat dataMeans;
    cv::reduce(data, dataMeans, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG);
    data -= repeat(dataMeans, 1, FEATURES_SIZE);
}
```

However, probably you can't use opencv matrices with your dimensions.
You can instead use std functions:

```
// other includes
#include <algorithm>
#include <numeric>
#include <functional>


#define FEATURES_SIZE 3

int main()
{
    vector<float> features = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12};
    for(size_t i = 0; i<features.size(); i+= FEATURES_SIZE)
    {
        float cumsum = accumulate(features.begin() + i, features.begin() + i + FEATURES_SIZE, 0.f);
        float avg = cumsum / FEATURES_SIZE;
        transform(features.begin() + i, features.begin() + i + FEATURES_SIZE, features.begin() + i, bind2nd(std::minus<float>(), avg));  
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the "minimum number of copies" optimal solution. Try with your large arrays and check if it is a problem.

Note: `using namespace std;` and `using namespace cv` used in my examples for brevity.

Hope it helps!